# How to find current transaction level?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, isolation-level

How do you find current database's transaction level on SQL Server?

Answer (score 323, accepted):

Run this:

```sql
SELECT CASE transaction_isolation_level 
    WHEN 0 THEN 'Unspecified' 
    WHEN 1 THEN 'ReadUncommitted' 
    WHEN 2 THEN 'ReadCommitted' 
    WHEN 3 THEN 'Repeatable' 
    WHEN 4 THEN 'Serializable' 
    WHEN 5 THEN 'Snapshot' END AS TRANSACTION_ISOLATION_LEVEL 
FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions 
where session_id = @@SPID
```

[learn.microsoft.com reference for the constant values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-sessions-transact-sql).

Comment: This one is not accurate if the isolation level is "read_commited_snapshot". In this case, it will only show "Readcommited".

Comment: @GaTechThomas , `READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT` is not isolation level, it is a database's option permitting to change the behavior of `ReadDCommitted` isolation level database-wide

Comment: @GaTechThomas, then how to find that READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT or READ_COMMITTED_Locked

Comment: @user960567, IIRC, Scott Ivey's answer would give those results.

Comment: this unfortunately does not work for SQL Server 2000.

Comment: @zzzeek - That's what you get for using a database that has been obsolete for twelve years.

Comment: This is not correct in some instances. If I have, e.g., "Read Commited Snapshot" isolation level, the above code will only write ReadCommited.

Comment: @StupidOne "Read committed snapshot" is not a distinct isolation level, so showing "read committed" is correct. It is a database option that changes the behavior of READ COMMITTED. To check if READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT is enabled, take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51977/208318

Comment: I understand the technicality of READ COMMITTED SNAPSHOT not being it's own distinctive isolation level but this will catch people out and did catch me out. Also MS themselves state it as an isolation level in the TABLE shown further down this page before the examples start so this answer could be improved by being more pragmatic and being in line with MS remarks https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-transaction-isolation-level-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: READ_COMMITED_SNAPSHOT behaves differently than READ_COMMITED, so it is isolation level in its own right, hence the downvote
In theory, we can be technically correct, but in practice we need to be realistically correct.

Answer (score 74):

just run `DBCC useroptions` and you'll get something like this:

```
Set Option                  Value
--------------------------- --------------
textsize                    2147483647
language                    us_english
dateformat                  mdy
datefirst                   7
lock_timeout                -1
quoted_identifier           SET
arithabort                  SET
ansi_null_dflt_on           SET
ansi_warnings               SET
ansi_padding                SET
ansi_nulls                  SET
concat_null_yields_null     SET
isolation level             read committed
```

Comment: and it points out "read committed snapshot" when active (see RC snapshot vs locked), at least on SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 35):

```
SELECT CASE  
          WHEN transaction_isolation_level = 1 
             THEN 'READ UNCOMMITTED' 
          WHEN transaction_isolation_level = 2 
               AND is_read_committed_snapshot_on = 1 
             THEN 'READ COMMITTED SNAPSHOT' 
          WHEN transaction_isolation_level = 2 
               AND is_read_committed_snapshot_on = 0 THEN 'READ COMMITTED' 
          WHEN transaction_isolation_level = 3 
             THEN 'REPEATABLE READ' 
          WHEN transaction_isolation_level = 4 
             THEN 'SERIALIZABLE' 
          WHEN transaction_isolation_level = 5 
             THEN 'SNAPSHOT' 
          ELSE NULL
       END AS TRANSACTION_ISOLATION_LEVEL 
FROM   sys.dm_exec_sessions AS s
       CROSS JOIN sys.databases AS d
WHERE  session_id = @@SPID
  AND  d.database_id = DB_ID();
```

Comment: Please also elaborate on the code to be more educative.

Answer (score 26):

```
DECLARE   @UserOptions TABLE(SetOption varchar(100), Value varchar(100))
DECLARE   @IsolationLevel varchar(100)

INSERT    @UserOptions
EXEC('DBCC USEROPTIONS WITH NO_INFOMSGS')

SELECT    @IsolationLevel = Value
FROM      @UserOptions
WHERE     SetOption = 'isolation level'

-- Do whatever you want with the variable here...  
PRINT     @IsolationLevel
```

Comment: +1 since its also prints 'snapshot' when it being used along w/ read committed (and not the default shared lock mechanism)

Comment: this is overkill, just do DBCC USEROPTIONS as thiagoh says

Answer (score 10):

If you are talking about the current transaction *nesting* level, then you would use `@@TRANCOUNT`.

If you are talking about transaction *isolation* level, use `DBCC USEROPTIONS` and look for an option of *isolation level*.  If it isn't set, it's *read committed*.

Comment: Also keep in mind DBCC USEROPTIONS is an awesome option for finding your SESSION'S isolation level, but it can be tricky - if your code changes the isolation level per transaction, those periods of time where the isolation level is different from the session default can be hard to capture. For example, if you open your session with isolation level x, but change the isolation level to y for the duration of a specific transaction within the session, the DBCC USEROPTIONS will not give you visibility into that if called outside of that transaction.

Comment: In SQL Server 2012 "isolation level" of `DBCC USEROPTIONS` is set to "read committed"

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT CASE  
    WHEN transaction_isolation_level = 0 THEN 'Unspecified' 
    WHEN transaction_isolation_level = 1 THEN 'Read Uncommitted' 
    WHEN transaction_isolation_level = 2 AND d.snapshot_isolation_state_desc = 'OFF' THEN 'Read Committed' 
    WHEN transaction_isolation_level = 2 AND d.snapshot_isolation_state_desc = 'ON' AND d.is_read_committed_snapshot_on = 1 THEN 'Snapshot Read Committed'  
    WHEN transaction_isolation_level = 2 AND d.snapshot_isolation_state_desc = 'ON' AND d.is_read_committed_snapshot_on = 0 THEN 'Snapshot'  
    WHEN transaction_isolation_level = 3 THEN 'Repeatable Read' 
    WHEN transaction_isolation_level = 4 THEN 'Serializable' END AS TRANSACTION_ISOLATION_LEVEL,
    d.is_read_committed_snapshot_on,
    d.snapshot_isolation_state_desc
FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions 
       CROSS JOIN sys.databases AS d
where session_id = @@SPID
  AND  d.database_id = DB_ID();
```

Comment: Your answer very barely differs from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21967158/2605758), which was posted over 7 years ago. You should [edit] your answer to include more details about your solution and/or an explanation of *how* this code block answers the question. This helps to provide context and makes your answer much more useful for future readers.

Comment: This answer does not count for the `transaction_isolation_level` value 5 that is set when Snapshot isolation level is set.

So a 

`WHEN transaction_isolation_level = 5 THEN 'Snapshot'`

need to be added in the CASE statement before the END