# How to check the isolation level of another connection SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to see the isolation level of all the current connections to find some locking issue.

I tried `DBCC Useroptions` but it gives me info only for my user.

I tried `DBCC PSS(0)` or `DBCC PSS(1,57)`
But I get the following error:

Incorrect DBCC statement. Check the documentation for the correct DBCC syntax and options.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find current transaction level?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038113/how-to-find-current-transaction-level)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
SELECT CASE transaction_isolation_level 
                        WHEN 0 THEN 'Unspecified' 
                        WHEN 1 THEN 'ReadUncomitted' 
                        WHEN 2 THEN 'Readcomitted' 
                        WHEN 3 THEN 'Repeatable' 
                        WHEN 4 THEN 'Serializable' 
                        WHEN 5 THEN 'Snapshot' 
                  END 
FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions 
WHERE session_id = <spid_of_other_session>
```