# Snapshot Isolation - perform validations in transaction while maintaining ability to rollback

Tags: sql, sql-server, transactions, sql-server-2008-r2, optimistic-locking

I am looking into SQL Server Snapshot isolation level. For simple updates, things seem straightforward and you can find lots of examples of how to handle. However, for logic which relies on data validation checks at the end of the transaction, I'm having trouble coming with up with a pattern that still allows us to ROLLBACK changes if a validation fails.

Take an example of a basic inventory table, where we want to ensure that inventory balances are not allowed to go negative.  We would have a check at the end of the transaction to make sure the balance is not negative, and if it is then ROLLBACK and throw an error.

Below is a SQL script example.
NOTE: your database must have snapshot isolation enabled for this example to work.  It can be enabled by the following command:

```
ALTER DATABASE MyDatabase SET ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION ON;
```

WINDOW 1: Create the inventory table with one item in inventory:

```
IF object_id('dbo.TEST_InventoryActivity') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE dbo.TEST_InventoryActivity
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.TEST_InventoryActivity
(   activityID int not null primary key identity
    , itemID int not null
    , inOrOut char(1) not null  
    , quantity int not null
    , modBy varchar(128) not null
    , modDate datetime not null default getdate()
)
go 

INSERT INTO TEST_InventoryActivity(itemID, inOrOut, quantity, modBy)
VALUES (1,'I',100, 'setups')
;
--show all records
SELECT i.*
FROM TEST_InventoryActivity i 
;
--show inventory balances
SELECT i.itemID, inventoryBalance = sum(i.quantity)
FROM TEST_InventoryActivity i 
GROUP BY i.itemID
;
```

WINDOW 2: Now open a NEW query windows and execute the following, which does not commit (this will be used to simulate 2 transactions occurring at the same time).

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SNAPSHOT;

BEGIN TRAN;

DECLARE @itemID int, @quantity int;
set @itemID = 1;
set @quantity = -75;

insert into TEST_InventoryActivity(itemID, inOrOut, quantity, modBy)
values(@itemID,'O', @quantity, 'test 1') --use Item 1
;

IF EXISTS(
    SELECT i.itemID, sum(i.quantity)
    FROM TEST_InventoryActivity i 
    WHERE i.itemID = @itemID
    GROUP BY i.itemID
    HAVING sum(i.quantity) < 0
)
BEGIN
    ROLLBACK;
    RAISERROR(N'Not enough remaining inventory', 16, 1);
    RETURN;
END
;
```

WINDOW 3: now open another NEW window and execute the following, which will drive inventory negative.

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SNAPSHOT;

BEGIN TRAN;

DECLARE @itemID int, @quantity int;
set @itemID = 1;
set @quantity = -50;

insert into TEST_InventoryActivity(itemID, inOrOut, quantity, modBy)
values(@itemID,'O', @quantity, 'test 2') --use Item 1
;

IF EXISTS(
    SELECT i.itemID, sum(i.quantity)
    FROM TEST_InventoryActivity i 
    WHERE i.itemID = @itemID
    GROUP BY i.itemID
    HAVING sum(i.quantity) < 0
)
BEGIN
    ROLLBACK;
    RAISERROR(N'Not enough remaining inventory', 16, 1);
    RETURN;
END
;

COMMIT;
```

WINDOW 2: Now go back to Window 2 and commit the transaction.

```
COMMIT;
```

When you check the inventory balance for Item 1, it is now -25, so our validations did not work because Window 3 had no reference to anything going on in Window 2.

```
--show all records
SELECT i.*
FROM TEST_InventoryActivity i 
;
--show inventory balances
SELECT i.itemID, inventoryBalance = sum(i.quantity)
FROM TEST_InventoryActivity i 
GROUP BY i.itemID
```

Output:

[image]

The inventory balance for item 1 is now negative.  I understand WHY the inventory is showing as negative, because the transaction in Window 2 does not block the transaction in Window 3, but I cannot find any references to how to use this kind of validation logic within a transaction and still be able to rollback the entire transaction while using snapshot isolation.  From what I understand, Oracle using optimistic concurrency out of the box, so I would imagine there would be ways around this.  Are there any patterns that can be used in place of this that will work with snapshot isolation level in SQL Server?

I understand that if I simply change the isolation level to READ COMMITTED, then everything works (unless SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT ON is enabled on the database), but am looking for optimistic concurrency patterns that would give the same results.

Comment: I think a more fair test would be to add a `WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:05'` in between the `INSERT` and `IF EXISTS` check in WINDOW 2 and then run it and quickly run WINDOW 3 (which does not have the delay) and the insert for WINDOW 2 will technically insert first, but will be rolled back due to WINDOW 3 successfully inserting and committing.

Comment: @Love2Learn I just tested out with the WAITFOR DELAY but the result is the same, because since we are using SNAPSHOT isolation, Window 2 would not see any modifications that began after its transaction started.

Comment: Doh, my bad. Try adding `WITH (READCOMMITTED)` to TEST_InventoryActivity inside the `EXISTS`. I tested this and it successfully rolled back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `READCOMMITTED` locking hint on the `EXISTS` query...

```
IF      EXISTS(SELECT   i.itemID, 
                        sum(i.quantity)
                FROM    TEST_InventoryActivity i With (READCOMMITTED)
                WHERE   i.itemID = @itemID
                GROUP   BY i.itemID
                HAVING  sum(i.quantity) < 0)
BEGIN
        ROLLBACK;
        RAISERROR(N'Not enough remaining inventory', 16, 1);
        RETURN;
END
ELSE
BEGIN
        COMMIT;
END
```

I used this query at a bunch of different places throughout the execution to confirm that the `READCOMMITTED` table hint (compliments this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038113/how-to-find-current-transaction-level)) does not change the isolation level of the transaction...

```
SELECT  CASE transaction_isolation_level 
        WHEN 0 THEN 'Unspecified' 
        WHEN 1 THEN 'ReadUncommitted' 
        WHEN 2 THEN 'ReadCommitted' 
        WHEN 3 THEN 'Repeatable' 
        WHEN 4 THEN 'Serializable' 
        WHEN 5 THEN 'Snapshot' END AS TRANSACTION_ISOLATION_LEVEL 
FROM    sys.dm_exec_sessions 
WHERE   session_id = @@SPID
```

Comment: Thanks for the input.  I'm not sure this will work if the two queries are executing truly in parallel and the IF EXISTS queries occur at the same time because neither transaction will have committed yet so read committed will still not be able to read the other transaction, and the select (read uncommitted) would not be blocked by the writes (snapshot) that have not yet been committed. I'm not at my computer right now but will check in the morning.

Comment: To some extent I think that is where this becomes a square peg with a round whole. You're trying to force transactional integrity without transactional integrity. I think the `READCOMMITTED` table hint is going to be the best you're going to get because it will at least get you information about anything that has changed (and committed as you pointed out) since you started the transaction. It will protect against the majority of scenarios. I think that with this your window for hitting a race condition issue is the duration of the query inside the exists.

Comment: Thanks for all of the info.  I think where I was getting confused is that I was treating SQL Server Snapshot as equivalent to Oracle Read Committed (since both are non-blocking reads), but they are in fact not the same b/c Oracle Read Committed allows for non-repeatable reads and phantom reads, where Snapshot does not.  You are correct that the only way to run these type of validations within a transaction is to "break out" of the Snapshot isolation level, and run your validations under a different isolation level (while still within the current transaction).  Thanks again!