# Entity Framework: TransactionScope has a different IsolationLevel

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, transactions

I'm trying to use a `TransactionScope` at Domain level, so I can manipulate data across (potentially) several repositories, yet save all that in the same transaction.

I have the following save method:

```
public void Save(MyEntity source)
{
    using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
    {
        var context = new MyEFEntities(environment.ConnectionString);

        this.Repository.Add(source.ToDbMyEntity(), context);

        context.SaveChanges();

        scope.Complete();
    }
}
```

But I get the following error on the `.SaveChanges()`:

> The transaction specified for TransactionScope has a different
>   IsolationLevel than the value requested for the scope. Parameter name:
>   transactionOptions.IsolationLevel

What's causing this?

Comment: Can you let me know the current `Isolation Level` in your DB? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038113/how-to-find-current-transaction-level

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that default isolation level for Entity framework is the one which is default for the database, for instance default isolation level of SqlServer is `READ COMMITTED`, while for TransactionScope default is `Serializable` so when you try to change it inside `using (var scope = new TransactionScope())` block it throws an error. Try something like this:

```
var transactionOptions = new TransactionOptions();
transactionOptions.IsolationLevel = System.Transactions.IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted;
using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, transactionOptions));
```